# Why my pc shutting down and restarting

Tags: motherboard, shutdown, reboot

Two days ago when i connect modem some time its showing blue screen error kmode exception and some time its shutdown and restart. Then i change modem driver and the issue solved.from yesterday my pc shutdown and restart. I saw event viewer its show kernel power 41. I remove modem but its again shutdown and restart. I wait in bios same problem.i change psu then change cable and power source. But same problem.then i change mobo and ram but same problem. Temp is below 60° c. How can i solve this problem?
Is my modem again damage new motherboard?

Comment: Is the driver maybe getting updated through Windows Update? Try to install the "good" version again.

Comment: I face this problem even in bios.Thats why i don't think its windows problem